# Why does std::ofstream add extra #13 (newline) characters?

Tags: c++, windows, newline, fstream, ostream

I'm working with a basic `std::ofstream` object, created as follows:

```
output_stream = std::ofstream(output_file.c_str());
```

This creates a file, where some information is put in. Let me show an example of such a message: (Watch window excerpt)

```
full_Message    "Error while processing message:\r\n\tForecast Request:"
```

All this is ok, but after having launched following commands, there is a problem:

```
output_stream << full_Message;
output_stream.flush();
```

In order to see what is wrong, let's look at the hexadecimal dump of the file: (this is a hexadecimal display of the file, as seen in Notepad++. For clarity reasons I've taken a screenshot.)

[image: Notepad++ Hexdump screenshot]

As you can see, the character `0d` is doubled, resulting in following display:

```
Error while processing message:

    Forecast Request:
```

(There's a newline too much, both lines should be directly one after the other)

I am aware of the addition of `#13` characters while doing file conversion from UNIX/Linux to Windows, but this is not relevant here: I'm purely working with a Windows file, on a Windows system, so there should be no need to add any `#13` character.

Does anybody have an idea how I can avoid this extra character being added?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Probably related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481553/5267751). [Or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520900/portable-end-of-line), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750636/portable-way-to-determine-the-platforms-line-separator), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689344/portable-end-of-line-newline?rq=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ofstream insert a 0x0D byte before 0x0A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173498/why-does-ofstream-insert-a-0x0d-byte-before-0x0a)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The streams default to *text mode*, which means that in Windows, if you write `\n` then the file gets `\r\n`.  Therefore , if you write `\r\n` then the file gets `\r\r\n`.

To fix this, either just write `\n` in your code;  or open the file in *binary mode*:

```
auto output_stream = std::ofstream(output_file.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: I had just this problem, thanks for the tip. Now I have new, UTF-8 problems. Text is fun...

Answer (score 4):

Because by default the library converts `'\n'` to `"\r\n"` for text streams on platforms where it's needed (like Windows).

So you don't need your explicit carriage-return in your string. It's handled automatically.

If you want to specify the carriage-return explicitly, then you need to open the file in binary mode.

---

When reading a text stream, the opposite conversion happens, with `"\r\n"` being converted to `'\n'`.